# Как создать action для таймера в React Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, асинхронность, setinterval

Есть таймер, который запускается через setInterval в action в редюсере:

```
case 'HANDLE_START': {
        return {
            ...state,
            hide: false,
            timer: Math.floor(state.value),
            timerIsTicking: true,
            intervalId: setInterval(()=>{
                this.props.handleTick() // проблема в этой строке!
            },1000)
        }
    }
```

По идее в момент нажатия кнопки, каждую секунду должен запускаться данный action:

```
case 'HANDLE_TICK': {

        if (state.timer < 1) {
            clearInterval(state.intervalId);
            return {
                ...state,
                intervalId: 0,
            }
        } else {
            return {
                ...state,
                timer: state.timer - 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Всем этим процессом управляет диспатч:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        handleStart: () => dispatch({type: 'HANDLE_START'}),
        handleTick: () => dispatch({type: 'HANDLE_TICK'}),
    }
}
```

Проблема в этой строке:

```
intervalId: setInterval(()=>{
                this.props.handleTick() // проблема в этой строке!
            },1000)
```

Надо как-то указать setInterval, какой action выполнять. Но как это сделать? Сейчас всё приложение вылетает с ошибкой:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Как исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout

Comment: @sinneren `this.props.dispatch({ type: 'SHOW_NOTIFICATION', text: 'You logged in.' })
setTimeout(() => {
  this.props.dispatch({ type: 'HIDE_NOTIFICATION' })
}, 5000)` - почему dispatch вызывается через this.props? Почему setTimeout объявляется сразу за this.props.dispatch?

Comment: ну через this.props потому что там пример без санок, у вас они, видимо, есть. ниже там же пример с ними. после потому что хотят убрать со временем нотификацию .сейчас понял,что это не совсем то что вам нужно